# How to set localstorage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in a solution in ASP.NET

I have my login .cshtml page with that code:

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(email, password, rememberMe)) {
            string token = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
        var db = Database.Open("BBDD");
        // Insertar token
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO token (token,date) VALUES ("+token+","+DateTime.Now+"");
         localStorage.setItem("var.token", token);

        Context.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
        return;
    } else {
        ModelState.AddFormError("Error");
    }
```

I want to set a token in the localstorage.

How Can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to HTML window.localStorage?

Comment: you should be using localStorage somewhere on your cshtml page like so.<script type="text/javascript>localStorage.setItem("var.tokern", token)</script>

Comment: My suggestion is, try to keep your views clean and specific to html and may some small logic to format html. Controllers/Services are the place you should be interacting with other services/db etc. If you want to set value to any javascript variables then set them like `<script type = "text/javascript" > localStorage.setItem("var.tokern", @token)</script>`